# Problems implementing a polymorphic stack

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a PolishCalculator as a functor, that recieves a stack implementation, adhering to a StackADT interface, and uses it to compute expressions written in that notation.

So I started to write the interface for the stack and it looks like this:

```
module type StackADT = 
sig
    type 'a stack
    val empty : 'a stack
    val pop : 'a stack -> 'a
    val push : 'a -> 'a stack -> unit
    val is_empty : 'a stack -> bool
end;;
```

And then I tried a concrete implementation as follows:

```
module MyStack : StackADT = 
struct
    type 'a stack = {mutable c: 'a list}

    exception EmptyStackException

    let empty = {c = []}

    let pop stack = match stack.c with
    |[]-> raise EmptyStackException
    |h::tl -> stack.c <- tl; h

    let is_empty stack = match stack.c with
    |[] -> true
    |_ -> false 

    let push n stack = stack.c <- n::stack.c
end;;
```

My problem now is that when I try to compile the MyStack module I get an error, saying:

```
   Values do not match:
     val empty : '_weak5 stack
   is not included in
     val empty : 'a stack
   File "StackADT.mli", line 4, characters 1-21: Expected declaration
   File "MyStack.ml", line 7, characters 5-10: Actual declaration
```

I understand that the problem is the fact that in the concrete implementation the type of the stack is not decided until we put an element onto the stack while the interface requires the stack to be already typed after the invocation of empty, but is there a way I can make this thing work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your interface when you write:

```
val empty: 'a stack
```

you are stating that there is exactly one empty stack, and that any stack can be build starting with this shared empty stack.

This is not what happens in your implementation since the type `'a stack` is mutable.

One fix is to replace this empty shared value by an empty value generator:

```
val empty: unit -> 'a stack
```

Comment: Thank you the fix worked, I just had to also edit the MyStack empty function to 
`let empty () = { c = [] }`

So basically as I wrote it originally I was stating that calling empty would return a reference to the one and only empty stack? Did I understand it right?

Comment: There were no call at all. So you were stating that a module of type StackADT had to provide an empty value and that there would be one and only one mutable field shared amongs all users of the module.

Comment: Wouldn't it also work to define empty as `+a stack (sorry, can't remember the exact syntax). The empty list is a valid starting point for any list the same way an empty stack should be useable for any type.

Comment: Mutable cells are invariant with respect to their content type, because they can be both read and written to. If user A push a function to the empty stack, then user B pushes an int, you don't want to let A try to read back its function and get B's int.